# why is localhost of pod resolved to node ip in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kong-ingress

I am using AKS.the DNS policy is not set explicitly,which should be clusterFirst.today I had a strange log inside pod during its starting,showing localhost pointed to the IP of node instead of 127.0.0.1.
who can tell me how does localhost work inside pod?

[image]

Comment: In the container, can you check what's inside /etc/hosts? If your container supports it, what's the output of `nslookup localhost`.

Comment: Is it running with `hostNetwork`?

Comment: no,it is a cluster network.with azure cni plugin

Answer (score -1):

Can you share the log and yaml file?

We can access Node IP with this:

```
containers:
- env:
  - name: NODE_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
         fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Comment: Hi Osta,I did not config environment variables in the pod.what I saw is the localhost:port was resolved to ip of node:port in the pod logs.